# JAVA DOM XML Parse

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a large XML file that I want to parse

XML - The XML file has over 300 cases and other tags
i'm only interested in the Cases. What I want todo is take all the cases and everything in the case tag and save it in a new DOM doc that only holds the cases, Once I have this New DOM I want to send it to another class that will take the information and format it into a word document( but i'll takle that once I get there)

an example of my XML is

```
   <suite>
<cases>
    <case>
        <id/>
        <title/>
        <type/>
        <priority/>
        <estimate/>
        <references/> 
        <custom>
            <functional_area/>
            <technology_dependence/>
            <reviewed/>
            <steps_completed>
            </steps_completed>
            <preconds> </preconds>
            <steps_seperated>
                <step>
                    <index/>
                    <content>
                    </content>
                    <expected>
                    </expected>
                </step>
                <step>
                    <index/>
                    <content>
                    </content>
                    <expected>
                    </expected>
                </step>
                <step>
                </steps_seperated>
            </custom>
        </case>
    </suite>
</cases>
```

There are about 400 of these case nodes

My java

setting up the initial

```
  private void setXMLdoc(String path){
     xmlDoc = getDocument(path) ;

}
```

getting the xml file

```
private Document getDocument(String path) {
    try{
        DocumentBuilderFactory  factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

         return builder.parse(path);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImportXML.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SAXException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImportXML.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImportXML.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }  

   return null; 

  }
```

would this create a new doc that only contains the cases?

```
NodeList fList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("case");
```

also how would I print out all elements todo with the case? / print out all the elements todo with all the cases

Thanks in advance - im still pretty new so sorry if this question doesn't make sense or seems a bit basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approximate code will be

```
DOMParser parser=new DOMParser();
InputSource source=new InputSource(<the XML file/network stream>);
parser.parse(source);
Element docElement=parser.getDocument().getDocumentElement();
XPath xPath=xPathFactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expression_=xPath.compile("//case");
NodeList list_=(NodeList)expression_.evaluate(docElement,XPathConstants.NODESET);DocumentBuilder documentBuilder=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document newDocument=documentBuilder.newDocument();
    Element newElement=newDocument.createElement("SOME_NAME");
    newDocument.appendChild(newElement);
    for(int i=0;i<list_.getLength();i++){Node n=newDocument.importNode(list_.item(i),true);newElement.appendChild(n);}
```

then send the 'newDocument' to the other class

Comment: I have used Xerces specific classes, which is not strictly necessary,

Comment: Thanks i'll try that now. looks good I never heard of Xpath so i'll research that a bit.